# How to mock Rails::configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, ruby-mocha

I'm attempting to test a class which makes use of the rails configuration file.  I'd like to mock Rails::configuration.

I've tried things like

```
Rails::singleton_class.expects(:configuration).returns('result')
Rails::singleton_class.stubs(:configuration).returns('result')
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rails.stubs(:configuration).returns(Rails::Application::Configuration.allocate)
```

This answer on [mocking a Net response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510719/mocha-cucumber-to-mock-the-net-response)
helped

Answer (score 2):

```
Rails.expects(:configuration).returns('result')
```

Please note there was a typo in your example. The returned value must be passed using `returns`, not `return`.

Also note, `Rails.configuration` returns `Rails.application.config`. If your method doesn't use `Rails.configuration` directly, it might actually bypass the call and your expectation won't work.